# error in terminal trying to create a react app (screenshot)

Tags: create-react-app

i started doing a react tutorial from youtube, following along with the instructions on setting up a basic react app and i ran into this error actually trying to create the app via the terminal in VScode. have you ever encountered this? any fixes?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPhV2.png) (see highlighted part of screenshot)
[terminal error][2]

Comment: trying this: https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/

Comment: If you copy the backtraces and error messages into the question. It will get search hits and result in more responses that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Start on a fresh project directory eg my-first-project
Then open that folder in a your VSCode and in the VSCode cli, run npx create-react-app .(the . indicates that it should install it in the current directory)
then open src folder and start adding your own components